# How to copy a one2many field in odoo

Tags: odoo

I would like to know how to copy a one2many field in odoo 14 .

Suppose i have a Model called "ModelA" with a one2many field ,which is related to a field stored in another model called "ModelB".
When i change a value of this one2many field in "ModelA", this change is passed on the "ModelB" field .
So i just want to copy the values of the one2many field in the "ModelA", so that changes will affect only the "modelA".

If possible i would like to keep the "one2many" type in the "modelA".
Thanks